# Excel Formula to get the % of cases with Average below 5

Tags: excel, count, average, formula, percentage

I'm looking to build a formula to count the number of times that an average is below the number 5. To specify the question:

```
_|__________A__________|__B___|__C___|____D______
1| PRODUCTS            | WEB1 | WEB2 | TELEPHONE
2| MORE THAN 1 PRODUCT |      |      |    1
3| INSURANCE           |      |      |    3
4| RRVV                |      |      |    5
5| PPP                 |      |      |    7
6| INSURANCE           |  4   |   5  |  
7| MMHH                |  3   |   3  |
8| INSURANCE           |  3   |   7  |
```

What I need is to get % of Insurance cases that have an average below 5 in one formula, as to get a total.

In this particular case, there are 3 rows matching the Product Criteria (Insurance), but only 2 of them have an average below 5 (last row is exactly 5). So the answer should be 67% (66.6666...)

I have tried countifs, sumifs, sumproduct, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=(SUM((1/MMULT((B2:D8<>"")*1,TRANSPOSE(B1:D1<>"")*1)*MMULT(B2:D8*1,TRANSPOSE(B1:D1<>"")*1)*(A2:A8="insurance")<5)*1)-COUNTIF(A2:A8,"<>insurance"))/COUNTIF(A2:A8,"insurance")
```

Confirm with ctrl+shift+enter.

It might not be an optimal solution but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column.  In E2 put the following array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A2="INSURANCE",IF(ISNUMBER(B2:D2),B2:D2)))
```

Being an array after pating it in the formula bar, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter.

Then you can use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(E2:E8,"<"&5,E2:E8,">"&0)/COUNTIF(E2:E8,">"&0)
```

[image]

Comment: i thought about it but i want to save this solution as a last resource. i want to keep my DB as clean as possible. i have to say that this solution will work, so if anybody else is facing a similar conundrum, it will do.  thanks anyway.

Comment: @DiegoRibba to my knowledge, which in no way is all inclusive, there is no way to do this without the helper column.  I hope I am wrong, because I will learn something if someone is able to do it.